# Not seeing my view in simulator using XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

[image]I have downloaded Xcode 4.2 and I'm having problems viewing my project in the simulator. I'm getting a blank whit view when I run the simulator. I'm using a single view application. I created a interface .h, .m, .xib... I have connected all actions and outlets and saved everything. My thoughts are that I have overlooked something simple. again, I just started using Xcode 4.2 today. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are not doing this

```
    if((self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyClass" bundle:nil])) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: in your view controller init method. Just paste your viewcontroller.m code here.

Comment: What do you mean by "do stuff"?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't enough information to tell what's wrong with your code.

That said, if create new project in XCode using the "Single View Application" template you can see how everything is hooked up and you may be solve your problem with a 'how is mine different?' comparison.

If that fails... post some code and we might be able to see the issue.

Edit: From your screenshot it looks like you are mixing storyboards and XIBs. If you are using storyboards, then you won't see .xib files. They are inside your storyboard. You can click on the storyboard file and edit the first XIB which loads when your app runs as well as create new ones. You can still do things the "old" way by just unchecking storyboards when you first create the app. On a side note, it is possible to mix storyboards and straight XIBs, but I don't think that's what you were going for.

At a guess, you created a project with storyboards, then added a XIB manually and you get a blank XIB. Try clicking on the storyboard and modifying the XIB in there. I bet they will show up when you run your app.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with main storyboard?

Comment: Uploaded a pic that might help